# WordPressプラグインの「CustomFieldSuite」に挿入した値をパーマリンクに設定したい

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

WordPressプラグインの「CustomFieldSuite」を使用したサイトを構築しています。

カスタム投稿はCPTUIを使用し「merchandise」としていまして
そこにCFSを適用して、「num」というフィールドを作成したのですが、そのnumフィールドに設定した値をスラッグにしたいのです。

例）https://xxx.com/merchandise/numの値

いろいろと調べてみたのですが
類似プラグインのAdvanceCustomFieldの例しか掲載されておらず困っております。

アクションフックを使用するのかなと思いfunction.phpにて
https://mgibbs189.github.io/custom-field-suite/api/save.html
こちらに掲載されているように値の保存などを試したみたのですがなかなかうまくいかず、、

もしご存知の方がいましたらお力添えをお願いできればと思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 単純には$post->post_nameを変更すれば出来ます。フックの例　https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217075/change-slug-on-post-creation

Answer (score 0):

おそらくこれが参考になるかと思います。

[ワードプレス　投稿スラッグをカスタムフィールドの値で置き換える方法](https://ja-ja.jp/archives/449)

紹介されているのは以下のような仕組みだと思います。

- カスタムフィールドの値で
- 記事の保存をするときにスラッグを書き換えてから保存する

なので、カスタムフィールドを使わなくてもスラッグを使うといいんじゃないでしょうかね？
カスタムフィールドを使いたいという強い理由があるのかもしれませんが。

またパーマリンクはpostnameで設定しておかないと反映されないと思いますので合わせてご確認ください。